# Coordinate System Rotation and Cross Term

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

If I have a conic equation $$ 5x^2 - 4xy + 8y^2 = 36 $$
and 
$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
5 & -2\\
-2 & 8
\end{array}\right]
$ in matrix form, whose eigenvalues are 4 and 9, how would I rotate the coordinate system such that there is no cross term. Also, how do I identify the type of conic section by doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I answered this question already http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608814/conic-matrix-and-diagonalization/608835#608835

Maybe you should take the time to understand what I wrote instead of asking again. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. But, you ought to take time to understand what I wrote as well. Although this is using the same matrix (you should also notice that I have taken into account the help and work which you very generously showed to me), and I am now asking about the idea of coordinate rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every rotation in 2d is determined by a fixed point and a rotational angle. Given the eigenvalues and the center (note that no term of first order exists and hence the origin), the conic equation in new coordinate system $(x',y')$ shall be $4x'^2+9y'^2=C$. The equation obviously describes a ellipse (since $4,9$ are different and positive) or two lines according to $C$. We now know the fixed point is the origin, then it's routine to determine the rotational angle $a$ by identifying the original equation with the new one plugged into $x'=x\cos a-y\sin a$, $y'=x\sin a+y\cos a$.